# Unexpected behavior of C++ boolean function and impossible return

Tags: c++, return, return-value

I have just encountered an extremely strange result of the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int N = 3;

bool gen(int l1, int l2, int p) {
    if(p == N-1) {
        if (l1 == l2) {
            cout << "sth";
            return false;
        }   
    }
    else
        return gen(l1+1, l2, p+1) || gen(l1, l2+1, p+1));
}

int main() {
    if(gen(0,0,0)) cout << "yes";
    else cout << "no";

    return 0;
}
```

The program does absolutely nothing and it's only a simulation. Why does it write yes each time, even though I do not allow it anywhere to do that. Moreover, the output doesn't contain "sth" word. Additionally, when I change:

```
cout << "sth";
return true;
```

into:

```
cout << "sth";
return false;
```

it still produces `"yes"` as output.

How can it happen?

Comment: Your code invokes UB. It doesn't return a value if `l1 != l2` but `p == N-1`. Your compiler should normally warn about this -- keep an eye on those warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your function will exit without actually hitting a `return` if `p == N-1` and `l1 != l2`. Your compiler would have warned you about this if it was set to a reasonable warning level.

This triggers Undefined Behavior, thus any output may happen. (I get "No" with clang for example.)

Comment: I know it can return nothing, but I didn't know that it can lead to something like this. I thought it was about || operator.